# Moving DIV disable button 0px left-margin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a little problem. Im trying to create my own slider using jQuery and some css/javascript.

I got my slider to work moving a Div 660px to the left and right by clicking a button.

But, I would like to have the right button disabled when the left margin is 0. And I would like the whole div to rewind back to 0px after some clicks.

Is this possible?

Here is my code:

```
<script language="javascript">
            function example_animate(px) {
                        $('#slide').animate({
                            'marginLeft' : px
                });
            }
        </script>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="contr-left">
                    <a type="button" value="Move Left" onclick="example_animate('-=600px')"><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-left fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" ></i></a>
                </div>
                <div id="carreview" class="carousel" data-ride="carousel" style="opacity: 1; display: block;">
                    <div class="wrapper-outer">
                        <div class="wrapper-inner" id="slide">
                            <?php get_template_part('loop-reviews');?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="contr-right">
                        <a type="button" value="Move Right" onclick="example_animate('+=600px')"><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" ></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div> 
        </div>
```

The code im using is from this page: [Page](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-relative-move-div-left-right/)

Well, with the code from Rayn i got the button to hide, but now it won't show when left-margin is 1px or something. So I'm trying this now: (doesn't work btw)

Im trying this now: (doesn't work btw)`function example_animate(px) {

```
                $('#slide').animate({
                    'marginLeft' : px
        });
       var slidemarginleft = $('#slide').css('margin-left'); //this gets the value of margin-left
       if(slidemarginleft == '0px'){
          $('.contr-right').hide();
      } else (slidemarginleft == '1px') {
            $('.contr-right').show();
         }
       }`
```

Also I'm seeing that the margin-left isn't set in the style sheet but in the
 `<div style="margin-left:0px">content</div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do an if statement after each click to check if the element has 0px

```
    function example_animate(px) {

                    $('#slide').animate({
                        'marginLeft' : px
            });
           var slidemarginleft = $('#slide').css('margin-left'); //this gets the value of margin-left
           if(slidemarginleft == '0px'){
              $('.contr-right').hide();
             }
           }
```

Comment: Why isn't the right controler hidden from the start. It disappears when i click it...

Comment: Because the #slide margin-left is getting updated every time you run that click function, you would have to check every time if the new value is 0px. If it's not disabling when the margin-left goes in to minus figures e.g. -50px, then in the IF statement, do

              `if(slidemarginleft <= '0px'){
               $('.contr-right').hide();
              }`

Comment: Also on the document load, you can hide the right button off the bat by checking the #slide element margin-left, something like `$(document).ready(function() {
 var slidemarginleft = $('#slide').css('margin-left'); //this gets the value of margin-left
           if(slidemarginleft == '0px'){
              $('.contr-right').hide();
             }
});`

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
function example_animate(px) {
                    $('#slide').animate({
                        'marginLeft' : px
            });
            if($('.xman').css("marginLeft")=='0px'){
                $('.contr-left').attr('disabled',true);
           }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Disable Button when margin-left: 0px**

You can use jquery's [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method to disable a button if a condition is met. Here is an example (in pseudo code):

```
function disableButton() {
 $(element).prop('disabled', true);
}
function checkMargin() {
if ($(element).css("margin") === 0) {
 disableButton()
}
}
checkMargin()
```

**Rewind to 0px after some clicks**

Here, I'd just set a count for clicks and trigger a function when it meets the threshold you want. Pseudo code:

```
var threshold = 5
var clicks = 0

$(element).click(function(){
clicks++
if (clicks === 5) {
rewind();
}
clicks - 5
})


function rewind() {
 $(element).css( "margin", "0" );
checkMargin()
}
```

Comment: Im not the best jQuery coder in the world. Is there someone nice enough to help me with this code and mine. So I could test it, if it works?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my working code, thanks for all the help:

```
<script>
        function example_animate(px) {

                    $('#slide').animate({
                        'marginLeft' : px
            });
           var slidemarginleft = $('#slide').css('margin-left'); //this gets the value of margin-left
           if(slidemarginleft < '-3000px'){
              $('#slide').animate({marginLeft: '0px'}, 400);
             } 
           var hide = $('#slide').css('margin-left'); //this gets the value of margin-left
           if(hide >= '-50px'){
              $('.contr-left').addClass('showMe');
             }
           var hideMe = $('#slide').css('margin-left'); //this gets the value of margin-left
           if(hideMe <= '-50px'){
              $('.contr-left').removeClass('showMe');
             }
           }
</script>
<!-- /Review script -->

<section id="reviews">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <h4>Reviews</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-1" style="width:40px;">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="contr-left">
                            <a type="button" value="Move Left" onclick="example_animate('+=510px')"><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-left fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" ></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div id="carreview" class="carousel" data-ride="carousel" style="opacity: 1; display: block;">
                            <div class="wrapper-outer">
                                <div class="wrapper-inner" id="slide" style="margin-left:0px;">
                                    <?php get_template_part('loop-reviews');?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-1" style="width:40px;">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="contr-right">
                            <a type="button" value="Move Right" onclick="example_animate('-=510px')"><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" ></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a href="<?php site_url(); ?>/reviews"><div class="btn btn-06">Bekijk alle reviews</div></a>
        </div>
</section>
```